# Sed substitution does not work with shell variables

Tags: bash

I use sed to replace strings in all files.

I have this, but it doens't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD="oldtext"
NEW="newtext"

grep -rli '$OLD' * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/$OLD/$NEW/g' @
```

But this

```
grep -rli 'oldtext' * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/oldtext/newtext/g' @
```

works! How can I fix my command?

Comment: Variables do not expand under single quotes. Use double quotes, and be careful you don't use some of the regex metacharacters in place of `oldtext` or `newtext`.

Comment: Tip: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically detects this and other common problems

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in randomir's comment and the question he links to, you have to use double quotes so variables are expanded:

```
old="oldtext"
new="newtext"
grep -rZli "$old" | xargs -0 sed -i "s/$old/$new/gi"
```

I changed a few other things as well:

- Lowercase variable names to avoid clashes with names reserved for environment variables
- grep `-Z` option to separate filenames with a NUL byte to deal with special characters such as newlines in filenames
- Skipped `*` after the sed pattern, as it defaults to the working directory anyway
- `-0` option for xargs to expect NUL byte separated filenames
- Skipped the (deprecated) `-i` option as the filenames go to the end of the command anyway
- `i` flag for the substitution to match the case insensitive matching in the grep command

Some of these require GNU grep, xargs and sed.

If you don't look at a huge number of files to justify grepping them first, you can just run a single sed process over them all, using a generalized `**/*` glob:

```
shopt -s globstar
sed -i "s/$old/$new/gi" **/*
```

This will complain about sed trying to run on directories, but it doesn't hurt; if all your files have a common extension like `.txt`, you could use `**/*.txt` to avoid that.

If, on the other hand, you have tons of files and you want to accelerate the task, you could use the `-P` option of xargs to parallelize:

```
grep -rZli "$old" | xargs -0 -P 4 sed -i "s/$old/$new/gi"
```

for four parallel processes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer! I use this grep -rZli "$old" | xargs -0 -P 4 sed -i "s/$old/$new/gi" and i have error sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s' keen you help me?

Comment: @J.Dawton That happens if your `old` or `new` variables contain a slash. You have to choose a different delimiter for the `s` command in that case, like `"s@$old@$new@"` - anything that is neither in `old` or `new` works.

Comment: It works! :D very very THX!!